# android async http - connect to different port

Tags: android, http

I am using loopj android-async-http.

I have problem geting this to work. I want to connect to 8081 but this code not workin:

```
AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient(8081);
...
client.post("http://10.0.2.2:8081/mysite/my_api.php",params, new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {
...
```

error I get:

```
java.io.IOException: Unhandled exception: Host name may not be null
```

Comment: Remove 8081 AyncHttpClient constructor

Comment: then it connect to 80. it is jloop's async http

Comment: How to use 8081 port using loopj android async http library